# How to index gruped object arrays parent and child

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have gruped array and i want to get data from it with nested loop. I can do it with using nested `$.each` but now i want to do it with for loop with indexes. But i couldn't get parent with index.
Here is the code that create grouped array;

```
categorized = (objArray).reduce(function (das, current) {
                            das[current.qgroup] = das[current.qgroup] || [];
                            das[current.qgroup].push(current);
                            return das;
                        }, {});

//So categorized is grouped on qgroup
```

Here is how categorized looks like:

[image: grouped array]

Now i want to get data from categorized like ;

```
var value=categorized[0][0].qtext; 
var value=categorized.parent[0].child[0].qtext;

//This one works but i want to use parents index :(
var value=categorized.KALİTE[0].qtext;
```

So need some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `categorized.parent` referring to when `categorized` is a global variable? The `window` object?

Comment: @trincot I'm not sure if i can get your question but i declared it a few line before my first code => `var categorized=[];` So there is no categorized.parent actually. I made it with `reduce`

Comment: So then what do you mean with `var value=categorized.parent[0].child[0].qtext;` in your question? `categorized.parent` is undefined, and it is not clear what it should be...

Comment: @trincot Sir i was trying to explain what i was trying to do with giving wrong syntax. Sorry for misunderstanding. I got the answer now, thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a array of elements not a object so you convert your obj to a array:

```
var newCategorized = [];

$.each(categorized,function(i,v){
     newCategorized.push(v);
});
console.log(newCategorized[0][0].qtext)
```

Comment: Yes! This is what i'm looking for. Maybe i should have seen this, feeling dump :) Thank you!